# あるコードでのみ「ImportError: No module named librosa」のエラーが発生する

Tags: python, tensorflow

はじめまして
私は今、tensorflow/magentaのnsynthを試しているところです
環境は
Ubuntu           16.04 LTS
pip              18.1
magenta-gpu      0.3.12
tensorflow-gpu   1.11.0
librosa          0.6.2
です。

対話モードで

```
>>import librosa
```

とやっても
pythonのファイルを作り、「import librosa」を実行してもImportErrorは起こらないのですが

```
#前略
"""Utility functions for NSynth."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import importlib
import os
# internal imports
import numpy as np
import librosa
from six.moves import range  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
import tensorflow as tf
#略
```

というpythonファイルを実行すると

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/User/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/8d760b4887a3a97dbc093bfa28201502/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.runfiles/__main__/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.py", line 23, in <module>
    from magenta.models.nsynth import reader
  File "/home/User/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/8d760b4887a3a97dbc093bfa28201502/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.runfiles/__main__/magenta/models/nsynth/reader.py", line 24, in <module>
    from magenta.models.nsynth import utils
  File "/home/User/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/8d760b4887a3a97dbc093bfa28201502/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.runfiles/__main__/magenta/models/nsynth/utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    import librosa
ImportError: No module named librosa
```

となってしまいます。
pipでインストールされているかどうかや、パスの指定も確認してみたものの解決策がわかりません
どなたか教えていただけませんか

完全なpythonファイルは[こちら](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NLzwn0dD5nHj8x-qIIBSsQeMqYJpTLV8/view?usp=sharing)です

＞補足

```
pip show librosa
```

の結果

```
Name: librosa
Version: 0.6.2
Summary: Python module for audio and music processing
Home-page: http://github.com/librosa/librosa
Author: Brian McFee
Author-email: brian.mcfee@nyu.edu
License: ISC
Location: /home/User/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: numba, scipy, joblib, numpy, scikit-learn, decorator, audioread, six, resampy
Required-by: magenta-gpu
```

また、

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
print(sys.executable)
```

の結果

```
[
  '/home/User/magenta/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline',
  '/home/User/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/8d760b4887a3a97dbc093bfa28201502/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.runfiles',
  '/home/User/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/8d760b4887a3a97dbc093bfa28201502/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.runfiles/__main__',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
  '/home/User/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
]
/usr/bin/python
```

こうなりました
回答お願いいたします

Answer (score 1):

pipでlibrosaがどこにインストールされているかを調べるため、次のコマンドを実行してください。Locationでわかります。

```
pip show librosa
```

次に、エラーが発生しているpythonファイルに次の行を追加して、インポートするモジュールを検索するパスのリストとPythonインタプリタの実行ファイルの絶対パスを確認してください。

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
print(sys.executable)
```

この結果をみれば原因はほぼわかると思います。複数のPythonがインストールされていて、対話モードとPythonファイルの実行環境が異なる可能性が高いと思われます。

Comment: 解決しました　ありがとうございました